# Enabling rubocop linter the right way

Tags: vimrc, plugin-ale, path

I've got a vim

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Sep 17 2020 21:54:53)
```

on ManjaroLinux (Arch + kde) and I'm using `rvm` to run my rubies.
The ruby I am using now is:

```
=> ruby-2.7.2 [ x86_64 ]
```

The problem I'm facing is lack of rubocop linting in the code (the rubocop executable can't be found by vim).

```
:! which rubocop
which: no rubocop in (/home/kaczor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin:/home/kaczor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2@global/bin:/home/kaczor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin:/home/kaczor/.rvm/bin:/home/kaczor/.local/bin:/home/kaczor/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin)
```

I've got the ALE plugin (https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) which should actually handle the code linting (and it did right after I've installed the rubocop - but not any more).

The problem is where my rubocop is located—it is located in: `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rubocop` (the folder is a part of the project).

So I should add a next path to the $PATH visible by vim ?
Or maybe there is a way to tell vim to use rvm (like call `bundle exec rubocop`) ?
I can see that the exec is defined in my config file here:
`~/.vim/bundle/ale/ale_linters/ruby/rubocop.vim`

How can I add this path to ALE/vim to load it ?
It would be nice if the path would be universal (so if I change the project to something different it would still work).

Answer (score 4):

Based on `:help rubocop`, I would do `let g:ale_ruby_rubocop_executable = 'bundle'` in your config somewhere:

```
g:ale_ruby_rubocop_executable                   *g:ale_ruby_rubocop_executable*
                                                *b:ale_ruby_rubocop_executable*
  Type: String
  Default: `'rubocop'`

  Override the invoked rubocop binary. Set this to `'bundle'` to invoke
  `'bundle` `exec` rubocop'.
```